# Return the bool statement directly VS using if to return bool

Tags: ios, swift

There is a question that I really want to ask for a really long time now.
Looking at the below code in Swift

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"
var flag = true

func checkA() -> Bool{
    if str == "Hello, playground" && flag == true {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func checkB() -> Bool{
    return str == "Hello, playground" && flag == true
}

checkA()
checkB()
```

It is possible to see that 'checkA()' and 'checkB()' is basically the same function since it return the same value every time. In my opinion(I never was good at programming), I prefer 'checkA()' as it is more readable than `checkB()`. Anyone can read 'checkA()' and just know what it mean but people(or maybe just me) will need to think about what happen in `checkB()`.

Is there any performance advantage in using `checkB()` instead of `checkA()` or is this just a preference thing?

Comment: There is no difference, and the compiler most probably produces the same machine code for both. Use what *you* understand better. I prefer the second variant, i.e. `return condition` instead of `if condition { return true } else { return false }`.

Comment: Same as Martin, I also find checkB more readable, and I suspect that over time so will you. As you become more experienced with a language you will find that (without going to extremes) _less_ code is more readable code. The more characters your eyes and brain have to parse, the longer it takes you to "grok" code. Use whatever you feel comfortable with for now, but do allow yourself to grow into the language as you go. As you become more comfortable with the language, you'll also develop a good understanding of how terse you can go without going overboard and obfuscating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t think it´s any performance changes in these, `checkB()` has lesser code and is much cleaner but more `checkA()` is more readable. It´s up to you what you prefer to use.

Answer (score 1):

Under the same optimization settings both of these guys should (in theory) end up being the same.

I decided to let Xcode tell me, however, which was faster (also it was an excuse to use the `measure` block in `XCTest`)

[image]

And the answer is `checkB()` FTW!

*The caveat being here that I just made a brand new Xcode project and entered this code - didn't play with optimization settings or anything*

### Test code

```
import XCTest
@testable import BoolTest

class BoolTestTests: XCTestCase {
    
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }
    
    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }
    
    var str = "Hello, playground"
    var flag = true
    
    func checkA() -> Bool{
        if str == "Hello, playground" && flag == true {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
    func checkB() -> Bool{
        return str == "Hello, playground" && flag == true
    }
    
    func testA() {
        self.measure {
            for _ in 1...1000000 {
                let _ = self.checkA()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func testB() {
        self.measure {
            for _ in 1...1000000 {
            let _ = self.checkB()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When making a "release build" where optimization is applied by the compiler, I doubt that these cases would be any different performance vise.